# vb.net WebClient.DownloadString fails to retrieve html

Tags: vb.net, webclient, downloadstring

Can anyone help explain why the  code below  fails to retrieve the html

```
Dim WebReqeust As WebClient = New WebClient
Dim URL as string = "http://www.professionalorganizervannuys.com"
Dim WebPage As String = WebReqeust.DownloadString(URL)
```

It fails on this particular URL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include user agent to your WebClient Headers Collection. I was able to get the html with the following.

```
Dim WebRequest As WebClient = New WebClient
WebRequest.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent) = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
Dim URL as string = "http://www.professionalorganizervannuys.com"
Dim WebPage As String = WebRequest.DownloadString(URL)
```

Comment: Lots of webservers are finicky about which requests they will honor.  When all else fails, use Fiddler2 to watch the headers sent to a website.  Compare those of a browser to those of your code and modify headers as needed.

Comment: It seems to me you can't change user agent in webclient. When I do download string it always get changed back to nothing